# Batching multiple agents based on location of agent

Tags: anylogic, batching

In my model I only want to batch agent which are at the same location. So my source block generates  the agents according to a database to a specific node (which is sometimes different for agents), now I want the agents that occur at the same node to batch in sizes of 2 and the one that are left over need to be batched alone.

How can I model this, I know that I can use the selectoutput (which says for example if location=node1 use this output etc) option, but do I than have to add for example manually 100 outputs if I've 100 different locations where the agents start or is there a more simple solution for this problem?

Added later:
Or is there another way to model my idea:
So I'm simulating an hospital environment, where logistic employees (in this case the transporter) based on predefined times collects the thrash on certain areas for example the databaserow I show in the picture below:
At 9:50, the thrash at thrash collection point at LAB_Office_2_H_T_N can be collected by the logistic employee.

So in my model I create this 2 agents (which are 2 containers, last column) based on this time and seize a transporter to collect this thrash. Since a logistic employee is able to collect 2 thrash in one time I want to batch it and let the logistic employee collect 2 thrash containers at once.
After that he transports it to the thrash dump area and is released.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to say with little visibility of your model and objectives. Do the agents mingle and move on to other process modeling blocks after Source? How do your source blocks look like..post a screenshot of this part if possible.

Comment: I've added more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors changed after the added information. You can use pickup and dropoff blocks instead. You can define your node requirements in the condition cell. You can use local variables like `container` and `agent` to code whatever you want. Or use "Quantity (if available)" option. There you can programmatically define how many units will be picked up by using your own function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yashar, This is indeed a good solution. I did not even think of the pick-up function!